# `atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit()` -- what do the various combinations of `success` and `failure` parameter do, when not equal?

Tags: c, assembly, atomic, stdatomic

The `atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit()` function takes two `memory_order` parameters, `success` and `failure` (as does `atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit()`).  Unpicking the C11/C18 Standards, I find that the allowed values for `success` and `failure` are:

```
    success = memory_order_relaxed     failure = memory_order_relaxed

    success =             _release     failure =             _relaxed

    success =             _consume     failure =             _relaxed
                                             or              _consume

    success =             _acquire     failure =             _relaxed
          or              _acq_rel           or              _consume (?)
                                             or              _acquire

    success =             _seq_cst     failure =             _relaxed
                                             or              _consume (?)
                                             or              _acquire
                                             or              _seq_cst
```

The Standard also says:

> Further, if the comparison is true, memory is affected according to the value of
>   success, and if the comparison is false, memory is affected according to the value of
>   failure. These operations are atomic read-modify-write operations (5.1.2.4).

Your ARM, POWER-PC and other "LL/SC" devices do a Load-Link/Cmp/Store-Conditional sequence to implement atomic-cmp-exchange, where the Load-Link may or may not be *_acquire* and the Store-Conditional may or may not be *_release*.

So I can understand: success = *_acq_rel* and failure = *_acquire*.

What I cannot get my head around is (amongst others): success = *_acq_rel* and failure = *_relaxed*.  Surely, in order to achieve *_acq_rel*, the Load-Link must be *_acquire* ?  If the cmp fails, surely it is then too late to downgrade to *_relaxed* ?

What is the intended meaning of the combinations of `success` and `failure` parameters (when they are not equal) ?

[It's always possible that I have been bamboozled by the Standard, and that the `failure` memory-order may, in fact, only be the read half of whatever the `success` memory-order is.]

Comment: Are you *especially* confused by "_consume"?

Comment: Not any more.  I now understand that the memory-order for the _read_ part of the _read-modify-write_ can (for some architectures) be applied **after** the _read_.  This makes sense of `failure` memory-orders which are not just the _read_ part of the `success` memory-order -- and that includes *_consume*.  [Mind you, I have yet to come across an architecture for which *_consume* applies... but that is another story.]

Comment: Consume semantics is potentially useful for nearly every arch that where acquire is *not* implicit on all reads and "free". That's a lot of multi CPU systems. But it has to be supported by the compiler, which needs front end to back end changes in almost all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of implementing an acquire load in asm on some ISAs is a plain load *followed by* a fence, e.g. on ISAs like PowerPC or ARM before ARMv8 introduced `ldar` / `ldaxr`.  **This later fence can be skipped if the failure ordering doesn't include acquire.**

An LL/SC CAS_weak might look something like this in pseudo-asm for no real ISA:

```
   ll    r0, mem
   cmp   r0, r1
   jne  .fail        # early-out compare fail
   sc    r2, mem     # let's pretend this sets CF condition code on SC failure
   jc   .fail        # jump if SC failed

   lwsync              # LoadLoad, StoreStore, and LoadStore but not StoreLoad
   ... CAS success path

.fail:   # we jump here without having executed any barriers
   ... CAS failure path
```

This (I think) could be a valid implementation of `mem.compare_exchange_weak(r1, r2, mo_acquire, mo_relaxed);` on some kinds of machines.

It's only an acquire operation so the whole RMW can reorder with earlier operations (the nature of LL/SC keeps them stuck together in the global order).  There's no barrier ahead of the operation, only after.

`lwsync` is a PowerPC barrier instruction which blocks all reordering except StoreLoad (i.e. doesn't flush the store buffer).  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ and https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/

---

To implement `CAS(..., acq_rel, relaxed)` on most ISAs, we'd also run a barrier *before* the LL/SC (to separate it from earlier operations, creating the release part).  That would execute even on the failure path, but would *not* create acquire semantics.  It wouldn't separate the load from later operations.

AFAIK you wouldn't want to put the fence *between* LL and SC to maybe skip if the compare failed.  That would lengthen the transaction and give more chance for it to fail from activity of other threads.

As always when implementing the C++ memory model on top of real asm, you do something that's as strong as necessary but no stronger, given the limits of what primitives the underlying ISA provides.  **Most ISAs won't make it possible for the CAS(acq_rel, relaxed) failure path to actually be as cheap as a plain relaxed load**, either because it's impossible or because it would hurt the normal-case performance.  But on some it can still be *less* expensive than if the failure side needed to have acquire semantics.

Some ISAs (like ARM) apparently only have full barriers (`dsb ish`) so even an acq_rel ends up draining the store buffer.  (So ARMv8 introducing acquire-load and sequential-release stores was *very* nice, since it perfectly matches C++ seq-cst semantics and can potentially be much cheaper than a barrier.)